# Running flask from port 5010

Tags: python, flask, apache2

I have apache2 installed and am trying to run this flask program from /var/www/html

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=int('5010'))
```

I have the ports.conf file configured to:

```
Listen 5010
```

I have the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file configured to include:

```
<VirtualHost *:5010>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>
```

However when I access the IP address from my browser http://XX.X.XX.XX:5010 it times out and doesn't display anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are unfortunately really confused. Your Apache configuration is totally incomplete, and anyway the `app.run` in your code is only used when you're developing locally, not when running with Apache. You should read the Flask [deployment documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/).

Comment: @DanielRoseman "If you have debug disabled or trust the users on your network, you can make the server publicly available simply by changing the call of the run() method to look like this: `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`" (as written from the flask quickstart page). Not to criticise but do you mind explaining the difference? Guess it's speed but wouldn't it work anyways?

Comment: Yes, speed as well as security. It would only be single threaded, for one thing. But note that that still wouldn't be running via Apache, it'd just be exposing the dev server to the world.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, are you sure that Apache is listening to port 5010 in virtual hosts as well? Try to add this to the beginning of the file:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 5010
Listen 5010

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:5010
```

As taken from the [Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)

This [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) might also be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Python code is an executable, so you need an Apache module like mod_wsgi to accomplish  that.  Follow [this](http://fosshelp.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-deploy-flask-application-with.html?m=1) tutorial; I have tested it on OSX Mavericks and CentOS 6.6. BUT, from your question I infer you would like to do a proxy pass, like as if Apache would transfer requests to the Flask server you are running on port 5010. In that case you will need a recent Nginx version. This, cant post two links because I ain't got enough reputation to do it so this is the link [https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ ]. The  Nginx config  on this link is for the Flask-io Extension but works on non-io server like you want. Modify the code for your needs.